# How do i reproduce audio from List<int> in flutter?

Tags: audio, flutter, dart

I have an app that i put together that streams the phone microphone using package [mic_stream](https://pub.dev/packages/mic_stream).

The package gets the microphone input as 8 or 16 bit PCM Stream but i haven't been able to find a way to reproduce the audio from the `List<int>` samples. The packages that are available seem to play sound from files.

Is there someway I can reproduce the audio from the `List<int>` samples that are recorded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

through this package you will find api called loadAndPlayUnit8List(Unit8List.fromList(List))
https://pub.dev/packages/soundpool

and another package also which provide same api called startPlayerFromBuffer method
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound